# Git pushed master instead of my branch. Why?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-push

I'm figuring out working with branches in git. At the time I had unrelated commits in master I wasn't quite ready to push, but I had to do a bug fix. I didn't want to create a new repo just to do a small bug fix, so I created a branch based off of origin/master

`git checkout -b example origin/master`

Its my understanding this creates a branch based off of the origin/master branch, and switches to the example branch.

I then went and did my fix, committed it, and tested it.

```
$ git status
On branch example
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

I then went to push it to master.

`$ git push origin master`

but instead of it pushing the commit in the example branch, I found this instead

```
    $ git status
    On branch example
    Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged,
    and have 1 and 3 different commits each, respectively.
        (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)

    nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

I don't understand why

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The syntax for `git push` is a bit obscure, but easy enough to explain for the particular case you are using:

`$ git push remote refspec`

The *`remote`* you named is the typical one, `origin`; this lets your git find the URL for their git.  That part is all good so far.

The problem occurs with the *`refspec`* you gave, `master`.

You might wonder: what the heck is a "refspec" anyway?  The answer is that it's a two—or sometimes three—part thing, with two branch<sup>1</sup> names separated by a colon:

```
ours:theirs
```

for instance.<sup>2</sup>

"But wait," you might say, "there's no `:` in `master`, there's only *one* branch name!"  Which is true, but `git push` needs two, so it makes up the other one: when you give one name, it duplicates the one you give it, so that `master` just means `master:master`.

This tells `git push` to push your current `master` and, on the other side, ask their git to update their `master` too.

If you want to push your current commit (`HEAD`) and have their git put that in as their `master`, you must<sup>3</sup> write that out:

```
git push origin HEAD:master
```

It may help to realize that when you `git push` something, *their* side doesn't care (or even know) anything about any branches on *your* side: your git turns your branches into raw SHA-1 values, and sends those—the raw SHA-1s—to the remote.  If your `HEAD` maps to commit-ID 1234567, for instance, `git push origin HEAD:master` has your git call theirs up and deliver commit 1234567, then send them a message: "now that I've given you commit 1234567, please make your `master` point to that commit-ID."  Their end then says "OK" (push succeeded) or "no, I refuse" (push failed, e.g., not a fast-forward, or permission denied by a script like gitolite, or whatever).  So any branch names you use that refer to *your* side—the left hand side of *`localname:remotename`*—are handled entirely on your end, and only the right-hand-side name is passed on to the remote git.  That's why you can use `HEAD:master`.

---

<sup>1</sup>Actually, any valid reference can go here.  Tags are references that start with `refs/tags/`, and git now has "notes" and such; all of these use references.  But branches are the ones most people work with most of the time.

<sup>2</sup>The optional third part is a leading plus sign, for forcing updates, a la `git push -f`.  Also, note that `git fetch` uses refspecs too, but in this case the names are reversed: `theirs:ours`, and you would normally fetch their `master` into your `remotes/origin/master`, for instance (with forced update, hence with a leading `+`).

<sup>3</sup>As usual with git, there's a configuration knob you can set to change the defaults.  In this case there are multiple settings, but the main one to consider is `push.default`.  See [the `git config` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html) for details.

Answer (score 0):

You explicitly asked git to push to `origin/master`. In order to push to a new remote branch named `example`, you should write

```
git push -u origin example
```

The `-u` causes your local example branch to track the new remote example branch.

Comment: I didn't want to create a new remote branch. I wanted to push from my local branch - example above - to the remote master (origin/master). What happened instead was my local master pushed to remote master despite currently working in the example branch - the branch with the commit I actually wanted to push.